# How we run selenium script using java on sauce labs mac.

Tags: saucelabs

I was written a Selenium script for windows and i want to run that script on mac but I don't have mac.
Is there any chance to work with a mac with same script?
I was thinking using sauce lab for it. But i unable to understand it that how we use saucelab for run java script on mac.

Is any body give me steps to work with sauce labs.

Answer (score 1):

Running on Sauce Labs is very straight forward. The first think you will need to do is create an account with Sauce Labs. Once you have an account all you need todo is point your Selenium Remote Webdriver to run on Sauce Labs. I attached a link to help get you started, I'm guessing your Selenium scripts are written in Java. https://saucelabs.com/java

Comment: yes my script are written in java for window and also,i have an account on Saucelab,but i unable to understand ,how i can run my script on mac machine using saucelab.as i never do this before

Comment: Should i also,download any desktop application for saucelab? or i can run my script online on saucelab? you can take me as a learner for saucelab.. so please provide me info in basic